# momentjs validate functions not working correctly

Tags: node.js, validation, momentjs

I am working on a chatBot where users are going to enter dates in different formats so I created a function to validate the dates they enter using momentjs with a list of popular formats I provided.

The problem is that isValid returns true even with wrong formats like (35 August). I found out that the last 2 formats in the array i provided are what causing the problem but i don't know why.

```
const validateDate = (date) => {
  const formats = ["DMMM", "DMMMYY", "YYYY-MM-D", "YYYY-MM"];
  const momentDate = moment(date, formats);

  console.log(momentDate.isValid());
  console.log(momentDate);
};
validateDate("29 Aug");     //Moment<2020-08-29T00:00:00+02:00>
validateDate("35 Aug");   //Moment<2035-01-01T00:00:00+02:00>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple:

D - represents the Day. 
M - represents the Month. 
Y - represents the Year.

In the case above the year is set to default 2020 (the current year)
That is why the 29 to August get default date of: '2020-08-29'

I think that the format you are looking for the second case is:

```js
const dayFormat = ["DD MMM"];
```

You can add it to the format list:

```js
const formats = ["DMMM", "DMMMYY", "YYYY-MM-D", "YYYY-MM", "DD MMM"];
```

The problem exists when mixing between different formats for instance, the last 2 formats: `"YYYY-MM-D"` and `"YYYY-MM"`. made to the original date mistake since the day was translated to a year.

I think that you should do as follows:

1. make sure you enable all those formats and make no conflict between the formats as you have right now.
2. I think in those cases it is better to customize the validation function so it will be easy to maintain.
   Here is an example of a customizing option:

```js
const formatValidator = (value, validFormats) => {
    return moment(value, validFormats, true).isValid()
}

const validateDate = (date) => {
    const formats = ["DD MMM", "DMMM", "DMMMYY", "YYYY-MM-D", "YYYY-MM"] // original
    const momentDate = moment(date, formats)
    console.log(formatValidator(momentDate, formats))
}
validateDate("29 Aug")
validateDate("35 Aug")
```